# Малюнок та рисунок

Tags: вибір-слова

В [відео-уроці](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1-t8O4Yud0) О.Авраменко радить розмежовувати вжити "малюнок" і "рисунок"

> Малюнок - кольорове зображення виконане фарбами.  Рисунок - зображення
>   нанесене штрихами/рисками.

СУМ-11

> [Малюнок](http://sum.in.ua/s/maljunok) - 1. род. нка. Зображення предмета на площині, зроблене
>   олівцем, пером, фарбами тощо.
>
> [Рисунок](http://sum.in.ua/s/rysunok) - 1. род. нка. Те саме, що малюнок 1, 2.

В [словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA) дані слова представлені, як синоніми.

Отже, чи дійсно варто розмежовувати вживання даних слів? Як бути, коли підписуємо діаграму в дипломній роботі/науковій статті (рисунок чи малюнок), адже вона може бути і кольорова і чорно-білою?

Comment: Ніколи не стрічав _малюнок_ як _діяґрами_ в серйозних навкових справах, всюди _рисунок_. Зазначу, що _штрихи_, _риски_ теж бувають _кольоровими_, тому це не арґумент. Також, певен, малоймовірно, що вони [_зафарбовані_](/q/3789/), коли відмежуватися лише згаданими тут означеннями. Але без цього і тому, чомусь мені здається, **рисунок**, навіть і суто художний, має деякі _закономірности_ чи _раційональности_, а **малюнок**, навіть коли технічний (але не для документації), це, так би мовити, від _душі_ чи за якимось невідомим плином. Очевидно, нічим підкріпити такі слова не можу.

Answer (score 3):

Посилаючись на Словник української мови за редакцією Б.Д.Грінченка, можу зробити висновок, що ці слова можуть бути синонімами у певному контексті, зазвичай у художньому стилі, але все ж таки мають відтінки у значеннях. Саме тому О.М. Авраменко й застерігає проти використання слів у неправильному значенні.

> **Рисувати**, -су?ю, -єш, гл. 1) Рисовать, чертить. Мальовали, рисували чорні брови мої. Н. п. 2) Обходить? Другого дня, як ішла на поле, то вже рисувала через дві різи. Левиц. Пов. 338.
>
> **Малюва́ти**, -люю, -єш, гл. 1) Писать (красками), живописать; рисовать. Не такий страшний чорт, як його малюють. Ном. № 4233. 2) Красить, малевать, расписывать. Ой там на горі, малювали малярі, малювали, рисували чорні брови мої. Чуб. V. 15. 3) Изображать. Ользі здавалося, що той вечір буде якийсь не простий, буде такий веселий, яким його малювала її молода фантазія. Левиц. Пов. 141. 4) Оставлять знаки отъ ударовъ. Нагай малює вдовж жидівську спину. Шевч. 136.